# How can I debug a web application that is running in iOS via the AirWatch browser?

Tags: javascript, ios, airwatch

I have a really "simple" problem.  I have an application that is internal to our company.  The company uses the AirWatch browser to manager internal web apps, which is fine.

The problem is, I have no idea how to debug or see the Javascript execution in that browser.  Is there a defined way to do this?  I've spent some time trying to search, but we've come up with nothing.

Comment: did you ever manage to solve this?

Comment: Nope, as of right now, the only solution is the AirWatch team looking into it directly.  We had to pull IIS logs and use Wireshark to verify requests from AirWatch to the MAG servers, but that is as much as we could get, no visibility into Javascript execution...

Comment: Yeah I gave up and had to resort to old school alert(variableName) style debugging.. Didn't help in the end as I had a problem with history.pushState and they have a very buggy implementation of it.

Comment: @SimonGates sorry to hear that, I think not having some developer debugging in place is a terrible implementation for something that is being touted as a secure enterprise standard option.  Fortunately we are switching to use safari/chrome so this won't be an issue for us anymore.

Comment: Anyone since solved this, or has everyone just gone to another browser?

Comment: No solution.  Our company switched to enabling other browsers (safari and chrome) to work through the network, so Airwatch is basically not used.  Airwatch support stated they had no way to debug client issues...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't debug AirWatch browser, only android and iOS apps using chrome and safari, when the device is connected via cable.

I usually implement a logging system that writes on a local log.txt file, and provide a button in settings to send the log file via mail.

Comment: Ironically enough, this is the correct answer.  It isn't possible and you would need to log stuff yourself.